# How to restrict DataFrame number of rows to the Xth unique value in certain column?

Tags: python, pandas

Say for example we have the following DataFrame:

```
A B
1 2
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5 
4 2
```

And we would know we wanted an x(say 3) number of unique values in column A.
Then the desired output would be:

```
A B
1 2
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

I thought about looping through the column in question, counting the number of unique values by tracking and taking the subset of the DataFrame with the right index. I am still a newbie to Python and I believe there would be a more efficient way to do this, please share your solutions. Appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can try [`series.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.factorize.html) which indexes the unique values starting at 0 and then select the values which is <= n-1 (*because index starts at 0*),hence  reserves order too:

```
n=3
df[df['A'].factorize()[0]<=n-1]
```

---

```
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  2
2  2  3
3  3  4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.random.choice` to select the unique id, then `isin` to select rows with those id:

```
selected_ids = np.random.choice(df['A'].unique(), replace=False, size=3)

df[df['A'].isin(selected_ids)]
```